# jQuery Reload div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make `jQuery` reload a `.php` file I have in my directory whenever I press a certain button.

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.loadimg').hide();
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.loadimg').show();
                $('#loadunasreports').hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loadunasreports').show();
                $('.loadimg').hide();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loadunasreports').show();
                $('.loadimg').hide();
            }
        });

        var $container = $("#loadunasreports");
        $('#reloaddata').click(function() {
            $container.load("unasreport.php");
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I press `#reloaddata` it shows and hide the `div` as supposed to, but it doesn't reload the `php` file in that `div`. However if I make it load dynamicly every 10 seconds for example then it works, but that's not what I want.

So how should I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't reload the php file"?

Comment: It's supposed to load a php file in a certain div but it does nothing.

Comment: Try adding a querystring to the request URL to ensure no caching (`$container.load("unasreport.php?" + new Date().getTime())`)

Comment: Can you also show the code that works? The dynamic loading you mentioned.

Comment: Why can you ensure that it does anything? Are you monitoring your requests are there are none?

Comment: try this `$container.empty()` just before `$container.load("unasreport.php");` then you'll know whether div is reloaded or not.

Comment: @JSantosh yeah it empty, but it doesnt load anything